# Is there a way to write the ip-address of an interface to a file when it comes up?

Tags: systemd

I'm looking for a way to trigger writing the IP address of a host to the file /etc/environment once the networking is up.

Right now, all my IP's are static.  I'd like in future for them to be DHCP as well.

For example: When eth0 becomes up and assigned it's IP configured from 10-eth0.network, the ip is written /etc/environment in some form like

```
private_ipv4=x.x.x.x
public_ipv4=y.y.y.y
```

I'll consider other options like perhaps a script that can run from a systemd service that can do the same.  I don't mind if it requires configuration.  For example, to tell it which interface and possibly network prefix is considered public vs private.

Comment: What do you plan to do with the data? Different use cases might have better or worse solutions.

Comment: True.  CoreOS Bare Metal.  I want to use it inside of the CoreOS version of cloud-init.  This isn't available by default on CoreOS... I'm wondering if there might be a reliable way of making it work without having to configure the ip in multiple places.

Comment: What is the point of using this solution where you can always use the `ip` command to get the address of any interface ?

Comment: I need it available in systemd service files.  If you play around with coreos you'll understand it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution found through this [link](https://github.com/coreos/coreos-cloudinit/issues/325) which works.
It seems that coreos-cloud-init writes COREOS_PUBLIC_IPV4 and COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4 to /etc/environment if these variables are in the environment before cloud-init runs.  This script achieves the same thing and can simply be copied to /usr/share/oem/cloud-config.yml

```
#!/bin/sh

workdir=$(mktemp --directory)
trap "rm --force --recursive ${workdir}" SIGINT SIGTERM EXIT

cat << EOF >"${workdir}/cloud-config.yml"
#cloud-config

coreos:
  etcd:
    discovery: 
    addr: \\$public_ipv4:4001
    peer-addr: \\$private_ipv4:7001
  units:
    - name: etcd.service
      command: start
    - name: fleet.service
      command: start
EOF

get_ipv4() {
    IFACE="${1}"

    local ip
    while [ -z "${ip}" ]; do
        ip=$(ip -4 -o addr show dev "${IFACE}" scope global | gawk '{split ($4, out, "/"); print out[1]}')
        sleep .1
    done

    echo "${ip}"
}

export COREOS_PUBLIC_IPV4=$(get_ipv4 eth0)
export COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4=$(get_ipv4 eth1)

coreos-cloudinit --from-file="${workdir}/cloud-config.yml"
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your distro, you might be able to have `dhclient` do the writing.

See: `dhclient(8)`, `dhclient-script(8)`, and `dhclient.conf(5)`

You can write the script `/etc/dhclient-exit-hooks`, test for the `BOUND` condition and write what you want.